# Python: Cannot call method from imported module

Tags: python, attributeerror, flash-message

I have a simple function to log a user in. It first comfirms whether the users details are correct;

```
import user    


@app.route("/login/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        _email = request.form['email']
        _password = request.form['password']
        if user.loginValidate(_email, _password) == True:
            session['username'] = user.getUserName(_email)
            session['loggedin'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Email or password incorrect!')
            return render_template('login.html')
```

Now for some reason when I try to call `loginValidate` I get an error that `'function' object has no attribute loginValidate`.

The module does have `loginValidate` which returns either `True` or `False`, so I don't see what the issue is.

`loginValidate` (within `user` module):

```
def loginValidate(this_email, this_password):
    db = sqlite3.connect('data')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ?", (this_email,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    hash = row[0]
    db.close()
    return hash == bcrypt.hashpw(this_password, hash)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you define a class in user.py?

Comment: I do not no, the strange thing this is that it was working just 10 minutes ago (so i know it 'can' work), so i must have accidentally changed something small that has affected this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
from user import loginValidate
```

**And:**

```
if loginValidate(_email, _password) == True:
```

Comment: Ah sorry if it was not clear, `loginValidate` is a function written in another module called user.py which is imported at the beginning of the module above.

Comment: @JackMoulson may I see your `user.py` contents?

Comment: @JackMoulson I don't see your `user.py` content. Still, I've updated my answer. Does it helps?

Comment: that sorted the issue for loginValidate but now the other methods are having the exact same issue so it seems like there is an issue with how `user` is being imported? also the link above is a gist of `user.py`

Comment: @JackMoulson Then `from user import *` or specify the functions you want to import

Comment: Thanks this has fixed it!

Comment: @JackMoulson My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't exactly point to where this arises, the error itself seems a clear enough hint. Python thinks that "user" is a function, not a module. Maybe there's a "user" function defined somewhere else, and python actually imports that